# How to handle blob data in Electron?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, electron

I'm using Github's Electron, which builds native desktop applications in HTML/JS.  I need to handle some blob data from the clipboard, but there are only methods to read text, HTML, images (JPG and PNG) and RTF data.  (http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.3/api/clipboard/)

I don't mind not being able to handle blob data in any specific way, I just need to be able to store it in a local database and then reload it into the clipboard.  I assumed I could do this using `readText` and `writeText` but I'm not sure that's possible.  When copying a PSD file and printing that out using `writeText`, for example, I get 0 bytes.

I see blob data as being anything other than the formats listed above.  So things like: .psd, .doc, .img, .bin, or anything with binary data that cannot be read in plain text.

How can I read, store and put this data back into the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, I suggest using Electron [File object API](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/file-object/) and store file path in clipboard for later usage.